# Editing Ignored Words in TeXworks Spell Checker

Tags: texworks, spelling

I turned on the spell-checker in TeXworks to check the typos in the English words of my LaTeX document.  It flagged several innocuous words so I was pretty heavy handed with R-click/"Ignore word" and I accidentally selected that for a genuine spelling mistake/typo.

Is there a way to edit the dictionary so that a particular (misspelled) word is no longer ignored.

Comment: Did you ever find this? I also just accidentally added a word :s